# Is it possible to transfer wordpress site from wamp PC 1 to wamp in PC 2? How?

Tags: wordpress, wamp, transfer

building a site on local host but cant access the wordpress from another pc, is their anyway to transfer wordpress from one wamp PC to wamp in another PC? or can we access the same wamp from a different PC? im a newbie sorry if you find it hard to understand.. thanks for help...

Comment: It's much easier to change your WordPress site addresses to the current hosting IP or hostname rather than copy your entire setup... http://cdn.inmotionhosting.com/support/images/stories/wordpress/change-url/url-settings-in-wordpress-dashboard.png - obviously make sure you open WAMP up to be able to be accessed by other computers

Comment: Do you actually want it on 2 PC's or do you just want to be able to see it from more than 1 PC in your network?

Comment: Hi, actually i wanted it (wamp) online and i did it somehow through editing "httpd.confg" in apache, and can access the wamp through typing my IP on another PC in my network..:)  now the problem is tht on second PC in my network  i can only see the site but can't login wordpress to make any changes  in the site....!! by clicking login link it goes blank/page not found ...! thanks for help ..:)